# i2c read register on /dev/i2c

Tags: linux, embedded, i2c

I have written a small test program that reads a temperature register on a LSM6DSO chip and display the temperature correctly after reading the /dev/i2c (IOCTL call) so far so good but whilst reading the chip through `iio_generic_buffer()` (which relies on the sysfs filesystem) correctly updates the register and returns slightly different values at each read, my program keeps on displaying the same value over and
over.

So question is: What am I missing? And why doesn't the register updates itself with the next temperature?

```c
int main()
{
...
   for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        i2c_read_1_byte(0x6a, 0xf, result); // reading 1 byte of register 0xf (WHO_AM_I)

        printf("Read %#02X\n", result[0]);

        i2c_read_1_byte(0x6a, 0x20, result);
        templ = result[0];
        i2c_read_1_byte(0x6a, 0x21, result);
        temph = result[0];

        printf("Read temph %#02X\n", temph);
        printf("Read templ %#02X\n", templ);

        res = (((unsigned short)temph << 8) & 0xFF00) | templ;

        printf("res: 0x%x\n", res);
}

int i2c_read_1_byte(unsigned char slave_addr, unsigned char reg, unsigned char *result)
{
    unsigned char outbuf[1], inbuf[1];
    struct i2c_msg msgs[2];
    struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data msgset[1];

    msgs[0].addr = slave_addr;
    msgs[0].flags = 0;
    msgs[0].len = 1;
    msgs[0].buf = outbuf;

    msgs[1].addr = slave_addr;
    msgs[1].flags = I2C_M_RD | I2C_M_STOP;
    msgs[1].len = 1;
    msgs[1].buf = inbuf;

    msgset[0].msgs = msgs;
    msgset[0].nmsgs = 2;

    outbuf[0] = reg;

    inbuf[0] = 0;

    *result = 0;
    if (ioctl(i2c_fd, I2C_RDWR, &msgset) < 0) {
        perror("ioctl(I2C_RDWR) in i2c_read");
        return -1;
    }

    *result = inbuf[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: I have tried with and without I2C_M_STOP and the result is the same

Comment: Why you don't use in-kernel driver for this module?

Comment: Using the driver means reading the sysfs ... this driver does not provide access to the chip's registers via this method.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, was a timing problem, so started with usleep and ended polling the DTA_RDY register ...